# How to query profiles by ID?

Tags: api, permissions, profile, metadata

My goal is to get all profiles (including customs) including all permissions and settings. I try to first get all profiles and then iterate over it to retrieve all permissions and settings.

However, I'm able to query `readMetadata()` by `fullName` only. If a profile has the same name, I only get the standard one.

I'd need another way to achieve my goal or is it possible to query by ID instead of `fullName`?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is subject to use the Metadata API only, I don't see a method to accept an `ID` instead of the `fullName`.

However, if you are able to also use the REST API, the URL to retrieve data of a particular profile by ID is (API version can be changed):

```
/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Profile/{ID}
```

If you need to find the ID of all profiles, the URL is:

```
/services/data/v49.0/query/?q=select+Id+from+Profile
```

To describe the metadata of Profile, the URL is:

```
/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Profile/describe
```

**Updated to provide more examples on retrieving Tab Visibilities, Field Permissions, Layout Assignments, etc. of a particular profile by its ID.**

The core idea is to find the relevant SObjects representing the meta and leverage the SOQL query in REST APIs (some of them are Tooling REST).

To retrieve the tab visibilities of a profile:

```
/services/data/v49.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+Name,+Visibility+FROM+PermissionSetTabSetting+where+Parent.Profile.Id+=+'00e0p000000WhKwAAK'
```

To retrieve the field permissions of a profile:

```
/services/data/v49.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+ParentId,+SobjectType,+Field,+PermissionsEdit,+PermissionsRead,+Parent.ProfileId+FROM+FieldPermissions+WHERE+Parent.IsOwnedByProfile+=+true+and+Parent.ProfileId+=+'00e0p000000WhKwAAK'+ORDER+BY+SObjectType,+Field
```

To retrieve the layout assignments is more complex. The first step is to find the RecordTypeId of a ProfileLayout relevant to the profile by (note that the URL contains /tooling):

```
/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query?q=select+LayoutId,+RecordTypeId,+TableEnumOrId+from+ProfileLayout+where+ProfileId+=+'00e0p000000WhKwAAK'
```

Then find the actual layout meta from its relevant SObject by using the following URL (take Account for an example; and append the RecordTypeId, not ID of the ProfileLayout in the above step)

```
/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts/{RecordTypeIdOfProfileLayout}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is with the rest API, many fields are missing like `Page Layouts`, `Field-Level Security`, `Tab Settings` etc. How can I get the whole profile?

Comment: Hi @Julian, I see. In theory, you can retrieve all related metadata about a particular profile using REST APIs (some of them are Tooling REST). I will update my answer with a few more examples. The downside is that it needs several round trip API calls and you need to find all relevant sobjects representing the meta. You can leverage the [Composite Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm) to reduce the number of API calls though.

Comment: One last question regarding the last step: How do you know that you've to query `Account` here? What else is necessary to query?

Comment: `<records xsi:type="sf:ProfileLayout">
    <sf:Id xsi:nil="true" />
    <sf:LayoutId>00h1U000003aCLhQAM</sf:LayoutId>
    <sf:RecordTypeId>0121U0000010tu6QAA</sf:RecordTypeId>
    <sf:TableEnumOrId>Metric</sf:TableEnumOrId>
</records>` 

This is what I get back, for example.

Comment: Hi @Julian, the second last query (on ProfileLayout), it returns the `TableEnumOrId` field which tells you what object each row is about. I chose the first one for the example which happens to be the `Account`. If you loop through the ProfileLayout query result, it should be able to query other things available to that profile and optionally filter out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

listMetadata() would give you all the profiles, including their Id and full name values. retrieveMetadata() only accepts fullName, however, but you can choose to use `*` to retrieve all profiles at once. However, it is generally ill-advised to name a custom profile the same name as a standard one because of the reason you've discovered. You can't specify a fullName to get to the custom profile if shadowed by a standard profile name.